# hiding file extension it self

Tags: php, file

I looking for your help please

I use simple php code like:

```
$file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
//echo $file;
$break = Explode('/', $file);
$pfile = $break[count($break) - 1];
echo $pfile;
```

than output $pfile e.g. fileforme.php

but that i want is output of $pfile become fileforme

because i want use it to:

```
$txt['fl']= $pfile ;
```

how to do? or there are any another better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pathinfo()](http://docs.php.net) and its PATHINFO_FILENAME flag (only available for php 5.2+)
e.g.

```
$file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
echo 'file: ', $file, "\n";
echo 'PATHINFO_FILENAME: ', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

prints (on my machine)

```
file: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Volker\Desktop\test.php
PATHINFO_FILENAME: test
```

Answer (score 3):

See [basename](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) in the PHP Manual:

```
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
```

or use [pathinfo](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) if you do not know the extension:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/index.html');
echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're looking for the filename without the extension:

```
$filename = basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], ".php");
```

Note that this answer is specific for the php extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pfile_info = pathinfo($pfile);
$ext = $pfile_info['extension'];
```

See [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/function.pathinfo.php) for further information.